# How to make a well-formed request token?

Tags: php, oauth, request, token

I am creating an OAuth login for my web app, and I am looking for the most air-tight and efficient way to create / store a request_token. As I understand, it will need to:

1. be totally unique
2. be time limited

What's the best way to create a unique token, and how should I store it (example, what would the table look like?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `md5(uniqid('', true));` + uniqie index + `char(32)` as a column is good enough.
2. No, it isn't supposed to be time limited. Look at twitter, for example - they have unlimited tokens. This behaviour depends on your API requirements and nature. An opposit to twitter is facebook - their tokens live for about 30-60minutes, afaik.

Comment: since I am rolling my own, this is the more useful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best using an existing framework like [oauth-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/). It has client and server examples which you can reuse. It support various databases including MySQL. The [MySQL schema](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/source/browse/trunk/library/store/mysql/mysql.sql) can be browsed.